# MacVim - How to properly set up vimdiff to work with SourceTree?

Tags: vim, version-control, macvim, vimdiff

I'm using MacVim as my editor and Atlassian SourceTree (v1.5.3) as my VCS frontend. I have MacVim's command line helper script `mvim` installed and `mvimdiff` properly symlinked.

I want to use `mvimdiff` as a external diff tool for different kinds of VCS repositories (Git, Hg, SVN) in SourceTree.

When "External diff"ing a file/merge conflict via SourceTree, both diff windows are just empty.

Manually diffing files via `mvimdiff file1 file2` works properly.

These are my settings in SourceTree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eQZD.png

How can i set up MacVim/gVim to work with SourceTree?

Comment: Have you tried giving an absolute path to mvimdiff?

Answer (score 0):

Your settings in the diff configuration are almost correct, you just need to make a little adjustment to make sure that (for example) git can find the binary. In the git docs, it states that the binary (in your case `mvimdiff`) must be in your path or else given its full path.

That leaves you with two options, either make sure that `mvimdiff` exists in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin` (or some other place that is on the Mac's *default* path), or do what I have just done and tested: put the `mvim` script in a known place in your `$HOME` directory and reference it there with the `~` (the only expansion that git supports).

So, I have created a folder in my Home folder called `.bin` (with a leading dot to hide it from the Finder) and then put the mvim script in there. Then in SourceTree I have set the 'Diff Command' to

```
~/.bin/mvim -d
```

and I have set the 'Arguments' similar to what you have, but I have put them in quotes to handle files with spaces and other special characters in them, so

```
"$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

NOTE: I have not tested this with `hg` or subversion, but since `svn` is supported via `git-svn`, it should work for subversion in that configuration too.

Comment: That doesn't work. For some reason SourceTree doesn't propagate $LOCAL variable to vim correctly. It's strange, it works in any other editor, but for some reason vim can't find the file and creates a new, empty one instead. I have a feeling, maybe because vim opens too fast and SourceTree can't extract source from repo to a temporary file fast enough. I don't know

Comment: Oh actually I found the problem. For whatever reason macvim adds another slash before the filename WTF?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the option -f to tell MacVim not to fork a new process, but it seems that SourceTree does not pass arguments correctly.

So, to use mvimdiff, simply copy mvim as mvimdiff (instead of symlink it) and change the last but 3 line of mvimdiff from

```
exec "$binary" -g $opts ${1:+"$@"}
```

to

```
exec "$binary" -g -f $opts ${1:+"$@"}
```